# Let $V$ a $K-$vectorial space and $W_1,...,W_n$ subspace of $V$.Prove $W_1,...,W_n$ are i...

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $V$ a $K-$vectorial space and $W_1,...,W_n$ subspace of $V$.Prove $W_1,...,W_n$ are in direct sum if and only if all element of $W_1+...+W_n$ is write of only form how a sum $w_1,...,w_n$ with $w_1 \in W_1$, $w_2 \in W_2$,...,$w_n \in W_n$

**My proof:**

> -> We have $W_1,...,W_n$ are in direct sum then $w_1+...+w_n=0$ if $w_1=w_2=...=w_n=0$
>   Then $w_i$ with $1<i<n$ have a single descomposition. this implies $w_1,...,w_n$ write how a only form with $w_1 \in W_1$, $w_2 \in W_2$,...,$w_n \in W_n$
>    
> **<-I dont know the other implie, can someone help?**

Comment: It's very hard to understand what you are asking. Is it: $W_1 + \dots + W_n = W_1 \oplus \dots \oplus W_n$ if and only if every element in $W_1 + \dots + W_n$ has a unique representation as $w_1+\dots+w_n$ ?

Comment: Yes. @Verdruss is that, sorry for the bad write.

Answer (score 0):

For the $\Rightarrow$ direction: Your proof doesn't some right to me. What do you mean by "$w_i$ have a single decomposition"? and how do you get from them to an arbitrary element? You should (for example) take one element of $W_1 + \dots + W_n$ with two different representations and show that they are the same (for example by substracting one from the other) .

For the $\Leftarrow$ direction: What is your definition of the direct sum? You have to prove that the sum of your vectorspaces fulfills this definition. Sometimes the direct sum is defined by the property you want to show.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I don't think you need to prove it because it is the definition of direct sum:

> **Definition.** Suppose $U_1, \ldots, U_m$ are subspaces of $V$. The sum $U_1+ \cdots + U_m$ is called direct sum if each element of $U_1+ \cdots +U_m$ can be written in the only way as a sum of $u_1+\cdots +u_m$ where each $u_j$ is in $U_j$.

From the definition, we have following property, which you can try to prove:

> **Condition for a direct sum.** Suppose $U_1, \ldots, U_m$ are subspaces of $V$. Then $U_1+ \cdots+U_m$ is a direct sum if and only if the only way to write $0$ as a sum $u_1+ \cdots+u_m$ where each $u_j$ is in $U_j$, is by taking each $u_j$ equal to $0$.